# Why "show invocation counter" option disabled in Call Tree View Setting?

Tags: jprofiler

I using jprofiler version 8.0.5. And i don't know why that option disabled. is there anyone can help me? Thanks you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wumJy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Invocation counts can only be displayed if the method call recording type is set to "Instrumentation" in the profiling settings.